# Computational complexity of $1/(x+z)$.

Tags: newton-raphson

Is there a fast method to calculate $1/(x+z)$ where $z$ is a root of unity and $x$ is real.

By fast computation, I mean is there a faster method than Newton-Rhaphson method.

Comment: Why isn't this simple algebra?  $$\frac{1}{x - (\cos (2 \pi/n) + i \sin (2 \pi/n))}$$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$

Comment: It is simple algebra of a specific form (The imaginary part). I am interested in knowing if this specific form can be calculated faster than an arbitrary complex inversion.

Comment: What does speed have to do with anything? This takes $0.000077$ seconds on a Mac laptop.

Comment: I am looking to calculate such forms efficiently for a more broader problem. The computation time on your machine reflects a certain degree of precision. Say accurate upto 20 digits. The requirement could be higher than this. That’s why I am interested in speed.

Comment: These details should go to the text of the question. As it reads out *currently*, it brings little to no clarity.